# turning a certain chebychev polynomial-like expression into a hypergeometric form

Tags: hypergeometric-function

Can the following expression be represented in terms of hypergeometric function

$$\sqrt{3}\sin(\arcsin(7/25)/3)-\cos(\arcsin(7/25)/3)$$

It looks similar to the one presented on [this site][1]

[1] :http://www.statemaster.com/encyclopedia/Cubic-equation#Chebyshev_radicals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\theta = \sin^{-1}\frac{7}{25}$, the expression at hand equals to

$$\sqrt{3}\sin\frac{\theta}{3} - \cos\frac{\theta}{3}
= -2\left(\cos\frac{\theta}{3}\cos\frac{\pi}{3} - \sin\frac{\theta}{3}\sin\frac{\pi}{3}\right)
= -2\cos\frac{\theta+\pi}{3}
$$
For $x \in [0,\pi]$, we have

$$\begin{align}
& {}_2F_1\left( -\frac13, \frac13 ; \frac12; \frac{1-\cos x}{2}\right) = \cos\frac{x}{3}\\
\implies &
{}_2F_1\left( -\frac13, \frac13 ; \frac12; \frac{1+\cos x}{2}\right) =
\cos\frac{\pi-x}{3} = -\cos\frac{x+2\pi}{3}
\end{align}
$$
Since $\cos\frac{x}{3} + \cos\frac{x+2\pi}{3} + \cos\frac{x+4\pi}{3} = 0$, we have

$$
\begin{align}\cos\frac{x+\pi}{3} 
& = -\cos\frac{x+4\pi}{3} = \cos\frac{x}{3} + \cos\frac{x+2\pi}{3}\\
& = {}_2F_1\left( -\frac13, \frac13 ; \frac12; \frac{1-\cos x}{2}\right)
-   {}_2F_1\left( -\frac13, \frac13 ; \frac12; \frac{1+\cos x}{2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Now $\sin\theta = \frac{7}{25} \implies \cos\theta = \frac{24}{25}$, the expression we have can be rewritten as a difference of two hypergeometric functions.

$$\sqrt{3}\sin\frac{\theta}{3} - \cos\frac{\theta}{3}
= -2\left[
{}_2F_1\left( -\frac13, \frac13 ; \frac12; \frac{1}{50}\right)
-   {}_2F_1\left( -\frac13, \frac13 ; \frac12; \frac{49}{50}\right)
\right]$$